# How to use the log file in Server with Xcode 5 continuous integration (CI, bots)

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode5, osx-server

I have scripts set up to run as post- and pre-actions in my Xcode project's scheme.  `printf` and `puts` in Ruby don't seem to print to the logs that show up on the Xcode continuous integration website's "Logs" tab.  How can I print to this log file?  Also, is there a way to find out where the log file is located?

Please forgive my naivety: I know very little about how OS X Server works.  The Xcode CI web interface is the only place I can see the log file:

[image]

Note, this is a cross-post from: https://devforums.apple.com/message/908997#908997

Comment: Do you see the Ruby printfs and puts when you run from Xcode directly?

Comment: @DougRichardson Well, sort of.  I am running `exec > ~/pre_build_log.txt 2>&1` at the beginning of my pre-action and post-action to route STDOUT to a file.  In pre_build_log.txt, I see all of the printfs and puts.  I'm pretty much a unix novice, btw.   When I try to route the STDOUT during in an Xcode bots build, I do see in the log saying that the user doesn't have permission to write to ~/pre_build_log.txt.

Comment: Ah! The Xcode bot is running as the _teamsserver user which has no home directory. Maybe that's the problem. Try routing STDOUT to a file in /tmp instead.

Comment: Good idea and thanks for the help thus far! Unfortunately, this is what I see when I try to route STDOUT to `/tmp`:

`/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000br00002y/T/SchemeScriptAction-BsxhMO: line 3: /tmp/post_build_log.txt: Permission denied`

Comment: Instead of writing directly into /tmp, try writing into the tmp directory specified by the TMPDIR variable. I believe that is the per-user tmp directory (though I am surprised the other one couldn't write to /tmp as well).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, writing to /tmp is what worked for me, here is an exerpt from one of my scripts:

```
exec > /tmp/testflight.log 2>&1
echo "uploading to testflight"
```

On the server running the xcode bot, your file should be there in /tmp as specified. I did not receive the permissions errors so maybe this will work for you.